# MySQL get count() from separate tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to get a simple count of rows in three different `MySQL` tables with a single query. Here is what I have:

```
SELECT count(s.`id`) AS c1,
       count(g.`id`) AS c2,
       count(r.`id`) AS c3
  FROM table1 s,
       table2 g,
       table3 r
```

This does not work though, I think its multiplying all three totals instead. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If tables have no relationship an cannot be joined, try this:

```
SELECT
  (select count(id) from table1) as c1,
  (select count(id) from table2) as c2,
  (select count(id) from table3) as c3
```

Comment: Perfect that worked. Is there a more performance optimized way to query this?

Comment: @Justin it could be optimized, but only if tables can be joined togheter... do they have any relationship?

Comment: @Justin then i think this is the only way. You could add distinct clause `count(distinct s.id)` on your original query, and it will produce the same result, but that would be much slower and i don't recommend it